# Why is rsyslog not working properly?

Tags: rhel, rsyslog

rsyslog is failing to send messages to `/var/log/messages` and to the external syslog collector as detailed below.

I have an AWS EC2 RHEL 7 instance and an on-premise RHEL 7 instance. They are both minimal installations, standard AMI, etc. The `rsyslog` configuration is default except for an added `.conf` file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` to send logging to an external syslog collector. The on-premise instance sends the syslog to an on-premise collector. The AWS instance sends it to an EC2 based collector. The two collectors are running the same software in the same configuration and are receiving events from other sources and functioning normally otherwise.

`/etc/rsyslog.conf` is the same between both instances. Here are the uncommented lines:

```
# grep -v "^#\|^$" /etc/rsyslog.conf
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
$OmitLocalLogging on
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state
*.*;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

On the cloud instance there is the addition of `/etc/rsyslog.d/21-cloudinit.conf`:

```
# Log cloudinit generated log messages to file
:syslogtag, isequal, "[CLOUDINIT]" /var/log/cloud-init.log

# comment out the following line to allow CLOUDINIT messages through.
# Doing so means you'll also get CLOUDINIT messages in /var/log/syslog
& stop
```

And on both instance there is also `/etc/rsyslog.d/listen.conf`:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/listen.conf
$SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog
```

On both instances `/etc/rsylog.d/xdr.conf` has been added. It varies only by the destination for syslog messages, see below.

Cloud instance:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-vm-39.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 09:04:02 UTC 2022

# yum list installed | grep rsyslog
rsyslog.x86_64               8.24.0-57.el7_9.2 @rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms

# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/xdr.conf
# Forward all log messages to Taegis XDR
# AWS Collector
*.*    @@aws-v-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:601

# On-Prem Collector
#*.*    @@scwx-collector.xxx.local:601
```

On-Premise instance:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-vm-39.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 09:04:02 UTC 2022

# yum list installed | grep rsyslog
rsyslog.x86_64                    8.24.0-57.el7_9.2          @rhel-7-server-rpms

# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/xdr.conf
# Forward all log messages to Taegis XDR
# AWS Collector
#*.*    @@aws-v-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:601

# On-Prem Collector
*.*    @@scwx-collector.xxx.local:601
```

The endpoint listed in `xdr.conf` is reachable from each respective instance on port 601. I confirmed independently through a quick `telnet` session.

```
# telnet scwx-collector.xxx.local 601
Trying 10.100.11.37...
Connected to scwx-collector.xxx.local.
Escape character is '^]'.

# telnet aws-v-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 601
Trying 10.200.2.89...
Connected to aws-v-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

The AWS instance is working fine. Syslog messages are delivered to the collector and to `/var/log/messages`. The on-premise server fails to deliver messages to both locations.

On the on-premise server, if I rename `xdr.conf` to `xdr.conf.bak` and restart the `rsyslog` service, `/var/log/messages` immediately starts populating. With `xdr.conf` enabled they are empty - no further entries show up. The external syslog collector is not showing any received events and `tcpdump` does not show any packets transmitted between the syslog endpoint.

**Why is rsyslog not sending messages to `/var/log/messages` nor the external collector?** The only difference is the endpoint it's sending messages to, which are both reachable and functioning normally from what I can tell. Even the syslog collector endpoints are the same configuration. Both operating systems are the same, and rsyslog is the same version. **How can I troubleshoot this further?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding out this is a problem caused by SELinux.

I found that SELinux was denying access to the `/etc/rsyslog.d/xdr.conf` file. When investigating further I see the following output:

```
[root@x rsyslog.d]# ls -Z
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:syslog_conf_t:s0 listen.conf
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:syslog_conf_t:s0 test.conf
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 xdr.conf
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:syslog_conf_t:s0 xdr.orig
```

I see that the `xdr.conf` file has the wrong context applied. However, when I copy `xdr.conf` to `xdr.orig` I see the correct context is applied.

By running `restorecon -Rv /etc/rsyslog.d` I see that it resets the context:

```
[root@x rsyslog.d]# restorecon -Rv /etc/rsyslog.d
restorecon reset /etc/rsyslog.d/xdr.conf context unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:syslog_conf_t:s0
```

I suspect this problem occurred on these on-premise servers because I uploaded the `xdr.conf` file via psftp to the `/root` folder and then moved it in to `/etc/rsyslog.d`. As a result, I think the file received the wrong context and that is why it is denied by SELinux. On the AWS instances, I am using SSM to push the file to the instance, which apparently it receives the correct context in that case. `restorecon` fixes the context and the problem is resolved.

During my research, I also realized I was using an obsolete configuration, and updated my configuration so it looks like this:

```
# Forward all log messages to Taegis XDR
# AWS Collector
#*.*     action(type="omfwd" target="aws-v-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" port="601" protocol="tcp"
                action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
                queue.type="linkedList" queue.size="10000")

# On-Prem Collector
*.*     action(type="omfwd" target="scwx-collector.xxx.local" port="601" protocol="tcp"
                action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
                queue.type="linkedList" queue.size="10000")
```